# How to select different option regardless of randomized variable

Tags: python

The question might be a little misleading, as there are no exact words to express my query shortly. What I want to do is make a random variable, and according to it pick one name from, let's say, 5 options. Then, pick another name from the same pool of options, however without being the same as the first name.

For example, if I have 5 students (John, Mary, Doug, Brandon, and Ava) and I want to choose between two of them, but not pick the same student twice.

Here is how I proceeded to choose the first variable using random.randint() function.

```
subj = random.randint(1, 3)
    if subj==1:
        subj1=='John'
    elif subj==2:
        subj1=='Mary'
    elif subj==3:
        subj1=='Doug'
```

(Note: value names are just an example)

Now for the second value, I have had some ideas, however I don't know how to complete it.
Any help is appreciated!!

Have a great day.

P.S.: As far as I know there are no other similar questions, or at least I couldn't find any. If there are, please redirect me there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about sampling directly from your list? The code below will select two students from your list at random.

```
import random

students = ['John', 'Mary', 'Doug', 'Brandon', 'Ava']
selection = random.sample(students, 2)

# Optional: Unpacking list
subj1, subj2 = selection
```

Comment: Would the result of this be another list?

Comment: Yes, I added an additional unpacking step to my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.permutations()` along with `random.shuffle()` like this

```py
from itertools import permutations as perm
from random import shuffle

names = ["John", "Mary", "Doug", "Brandon", "Ava"]
res = list(perm(names, 2))
shuffle(res)

print(res.pop())
```

First, the `names` stores all the names in a list, and the `permutations` iterates through the list and returns all the permutations of 2 names each; this is stored as a list of tuples in `res` and the `shuffle` does what it says, it shuffles the list in a random order, and at last the `pop` returns the last item in it.

Comment: This is genius! Thanks!

Comment: @GeorgeTsakoumakis You're always welcome

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
 import random
 names = ['John','Mary','Doug','Ted','Mary']
 idx = random.sample(range(len(names)), len(names))
 for index in idx:
    print(names[index])
```

This will give you a list of unique generated random indices. based on this you can select the names(let's say you have all of them in a list) and pick them based on `idx`.

Comment: Could you explain how this works? That is, how it would apply to my case?

Comment: Also, does this mean I ought to remove the previous variable subj?